# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress Windows XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

I want to configure local with xampp a wordpress website and I receive error message Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress".
I've already uncomment extension=php_mysqli.dll but still not working.I'm using php version 7.1.26.

Comment: Even though that was uncommented, did you also restart the webserver? ... any changes to php.ini requires a restart.

Comment: Yes I restarted the server

Answer (score 0):

There're few things to do to fix this error

1. Make sure you install php-mysql extension on your server
   In unbuntu use these commands:

   apt-get update
   apt-get install php7.0-mysql
   service apache2 restart
2. Enable php-mysql extension in php.ini file
3. Restart apache to make it work

Did you finish the step 1?
I suggest this tutorial with detailed step by step that may help you out: https://wooexplorer.com/php-installation-missing-the-mysql-extension-required-by-wordpress/